# Python stops responding to this code why?

Tags: python, loops, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import random

from turtle import Turtle,Screen

screen=Screen()

screen.setup(width=500,height=400)   #setting screen size

race_on=False

#creating user input for bet

user_bet=screen.textinput(title="Make your bet",prompt="whicht turtle will wint the race? Enter a color:")

print(user_bet)

#creating list for turtle colors

color=["red","green","yellow","blue","orange","purple"]

# changing y axis make turtle in diff positon in start

y_position=[-100,-60,-20,20,60,100]

new_tur=[]

#putting turtle to start

for i in range(6):

    tur=Turtle()

    tur.shape("turtle")

    tur.color(color[i])

    tur.penup()

    tur.goto(x=-230,y=y_position[i])

    new_tur.append(tur)

if user_bet:

    race_on=True

while race_on:

    for turtle in new_tur:

        if turtle.xcor()>230:

                race_on=False

                winning_tur=turtle.pencolor()

                if winning_tur==user_bet:

                    print(f"You've won {winning_tur} is the winner")

                else:

                    print(f"You've lost {winning_tur} is the winner")

                    turtle.forward(random.randint(0,10))

screen.exitonclick()
```

I have written that code and everytime ,I run it it shows python stops responding ,I don't know what is looping or not please find the error.

Comment: Of course it is looping.  If no turtle has an X coordinate beyond 230, then your final loop does nothing, over and over and over and over.  I SUSPECT you want that final `forward` line to be unindented so it is after the `if`, not part of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
while race_on:
    for turtle in new_tur:
        if turtle.xcor()>230:
            ...
```

I believe `turtle.xcor() > 230` is always false, therefore this is an infinite loop.